# Rails 3: Do I Need to Connect to MongoDB every time I want to find something?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb

Every time I need to get something from MongoDB I'm connecting to it. Is there a way I can connect only once (like a global variable) and use that variable in all the finds and actions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have pretty much nailed this yourself. My preferred way to do this is to use a method in an initializer or class in the lib directory that initializes a class variable when it is not already set.

The following assumes you are using the standard Ruby driver. I've stuck it in a module, but you don't *really* need to do this. I'm also selecting the database I wish to use, as I tend to use one per app.

```
# config/initializers/mongodb_connection.rb
module CachedMongoDBConnection

  def mongodb_connection
    @@cached_mongodb_connection ||= Mongo::Connection.new.db('my_database_name')
  end

end

include CachedMongoDBConnection
```

Now in your controllers/models etc you can call the `mongodb_connection` method and work with that.

Comment: This also has large performance benefits. One one app I run it does 3x requests-per-second with connection caching on compared to off. YMMV, the actions I tested were simple data collectors.